# How to play a video url from server in an iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4, nsxmlparser

Actually, I get a url from server by using `XMLParser`. I want to play this video url in my app.
Now I used `MPMoviePlayerController, but its not working. Please help!

XMLParser.m

```
-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
videoNames      =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

videos          = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData  *data   = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
parser          = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];
return self;
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:   (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
 {
 if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"items"]) 
{

}


 if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"video"]) 
 {
     NSLog(@"video");
 currentVideo = [Video alloc];
  }   
}


 - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname 
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"video"]) 
{

   currentNodeContent2= [[currentNodeContent2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+"    withString:@" "]
                               stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[videos addObject:currentVideo];
currentVideo.content2 = currentNodeContent2;


}
   if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"name"]) 
{
     currentNodeContent2= [[currentNodeContent2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "]
                          stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [videoNames addObject:currentVideo];
    currentVideo.content2 = currentNodeContent2;
    NSLog(@"%@",currentNodeContent2);
   }
  }


// in my class.m

 -(void)playButtonPressed1:(UIButton*)sender
 {
  UIButton *btn1 = (UIButton *)sender;

Video *currentVideo= [[xmlParservideo videos] objectAtIndex:btn1.tag];
   NSString *urlString=currentVideo.content;

NSURL *playURL=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];

self.player =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL
              :playURL];
      player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,80,340,360);
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];

self.player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown;

[self.player prepareToPlay];

[self.player play];
 }
```

my xml

```
  <items>
    <item>
      <pastor> Master Jojimon</pastor>  
       <video>
       http3A2F2Fvideo.google.com2Fgoogleplayer.swfFdocidD-675885207870876013326hl%3Den 
      </video>
      <name>Message by Master Jojimon</name>
        <lan>english</lan>
```

Comment: Why don't you show us what isn't working. show some code.

Comment: this is my xmlParser Code and action of play button

Comment: What does an NSLog of urlString right before you init show?

Comment: corresponding current video content(url)

Comment: now i post my xml and also help me to play this url. my mail id islahulislam.ca@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Its not working before that video string is not a valid url. A its pointing to an swf flash file which isn't a video. And B just typing in the url to Safari shows it as not a valid address.

If you were to handle for loading errors I am sure it would say its not a valid URL.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/embed/X_nJ7So9y04 this is working url , this also not play in my app

Comment: That isn't a video. That is a link to a flash player. Which also of course won't play in your app. You need a video to an actual video. An MP4 works best.